# CQL pagination through User Defined Type

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

Let say i have this table

```
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.post (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  title text,
  photos set<frozen <photoIds>>
);
```

and UDT :

```
CREATE TYPE mykeyspace.photoIds (
  photoId uuid,
  details text
);
```

How can I paginated through `photos`, means 10 `photos` at a time for given post `id` ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'paginated through photos' ? Do you mean you want Cassandra to return 10 photos set at a time ? Or do you mean that for a given id and title you want to paginate through the set of photos ?

Comment: Let say a post X can have 100 photos. So `photos` will have some thing like `[id1, id2,..id100]` So i want to get 1..10, 11..20, 21..29 image id for the given post id x

Comment: for the given post id i want to paginate through `photos`

Answer (score 3):

Paging through collections is not supported.

See [reference manual](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html):

> Keep collections small to prevent delays during querying because Cassandra reads a collection in its entirety. The collection is not paged internally.
>
> As discussed earlier, collections are designed to store only a small amount of data.

Comment: but `photos` is UDT not collection

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're trying to iterate/page through the _set_ of photos, i.e. the actual collection of UDTs.

Comment: so u are saying UDT is collection internally ?

Comment: @Manish `photos set<frozen <photoIds>>` In your CQL you defined photoIds as a `set`.  So yes, that makes it a collection (set of UDT).

Answer (score 1):

May I propose another schema for your table post :

```
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.post (
  id uuid,
  title text static,
  photo photo,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, photo)
);

CREATE TYPE mykeyspace.photo (
  id uuid,
  details text
);
```

This schema means :

- There is one partition by id => a partition is equivalent to a post
- There is one title by partition/post
- There is multiple photo ids by partition/post

This schema should serve your goal very well until you reach about 100.000 photos by partition/post.
If you have never used static columns before, you can refer to [Datastax documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/refStaticCol.html)

The driver can do the paging for you. See [Paging Feature](https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/2.0.10/features/paging/) in Datastax Java driver documentation.

The Cql query looks like this :

```
select photo.id, photo.details from post where id=*your_post_id*;
```

PS : I think you should not use uppercase in your schema.

Comment: I cant paginate through UTD type ?

Comment: here u are getting all photos at once not 10 at one time

Comment: The paging is done by the driver. You can find how to [there](https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/2.0.10/features/paging/)